# Loading Markdownify in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, markdown

I downloaded Markdownify from http://milianw.de/projects/markdownify/ and extracted it to my application/libraries/ directory.

I did a:

```
$this->load->library('markdownify');
echo $this->markdownify->parseString('<b>Test</b>');
```

But the output is the same html markup. It didn’t work. How do I get it working?

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you have all the necessary files in applications/libraries (markdownify.php and the parsehtml directory)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried renaming it to markdownify_helper.php, place it in your application/helpers/ directory and loading it so:

```
$this->load->helper('markdownify');
```